# Find the ratio between two groups

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, grouping

Essentially I have

```
Var1 Group Value
a    0     1 
b    0     2
c    0     3
a    1     2
b    1     10
c    1     9
```

I want to calculate a table with rows `Var1` and a single column `Div` where for any value of `Var1`,  the value of `Div` will be the division of the `Value` values for group 1 over group 2. Thus, the outcome should be

```
Var1 Div
a    .5
b    .2
c    .3333
```

I have achieved this by creating two tables (filter the table using `Group`, then divide the `Value` column of the two tables, and then create a new table). Is there a method or function in the tidyverse that achieves this using pipes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are 2 alternatives to match `Group` in each `Var1` stratum using `match()` and `pivot_wider()` respectively.

```r
library(dplyr)

quux %>%
  summarise(Div = Value[match(0:1, Group)] %>% {.[1] / .[2]}, .by = Var1)

#   Var1       Div
# 1    a 0.5000000
# 2    b 0.2000000
# 3    c 0.3333333
```

```r
library(tidyr)

quux %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Group, values_from = Value, names_prefix = 'grp') %>%
  mutate(Div = grp0 / grp1, .keep = "unused")

# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#   Var1    Div
#   <chr> <dbl>
# 1 a     0.5  
# 2 b     0.2  
# 3 c     0.333
```

Comment: I will keep my answer, :-)

Comment: I prefer using valid column names instead of `Div = \`0\` / \`1\``, so that `names_prefix = 'grp'` is used.

Comment: I agree. For a quick solution, I did not considered `names_prefix`.

Answer (score 5):

```r
library(dplyr)
quux %>%
  group_by(Var1) %>%
  filter(all(0:1 %in% Group)) %>%
  summarize(Div = Value[Group==0]/Value[Group==1])
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#   Var1    Div
#   <chr> <dbl>
# 1 a     0.5  
# 2 b     0.2  
# 3 c     0.333
```

The use of `filter(all(0:1 %in% Group))` is done group-wise and ensures that we have both in order to do the ratio. (Depending on your confidence in the data, a slightly more complex test would be to guarantee that there is exactly one of each of `0:1`, perhaps using

```r
quux %>%
  group_by(Var1) %>%
  filter(identical(sort(intersect(Group, 0:1)), 0:1)) %>%
  summarize(...)
```

which guarantees *both* and *no others* are in `Group`. (Safeguards on data integrity.)

If you need to retain those groups, however, **OR** you think it's remotely possible that one might have more than one of each `Group` within a `Var1`-group, then you can do something like:

```r
quux %>%
  group_by(Var1) %>%
  summarize(Div = Value[Group==0][1]/Value[Group==1][1])
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#   Var1    Div
#   <chr> <dbl>
# 1 a     0.5  
# 2 b     0.2  
# 3 c     0.333
```

The addition of `[1]` guarantees that we'll get just one value; if that `Group` is found, then it's the respective `Value`; if that `Group` is *not* found, however, `Value[Group==0][1]` will return `NA`, which is safe for both the numerator and denominator.

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(Var1 = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"), Group = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Value = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 10L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: A little complicated for me to follow. The actual data I have is from a contingency table, of size 10 by 4, and therefore I don't have much issues looking that the groups are actually right. Anyway, this seems to work. However, I'll accept another answer simply because it makes more sense to me and I can read the code and know (if I just use this and return to my code six months from now I will have no clue what is going on).

Comment: Choose whichever you want. I don't see how the last code block is all that complicated (it's vanilla R indexing), and it's far more efficient than any pivoting. shrug

Answer (score 3):

An alternative would be

```r
summarise(quux, Div = sum(Value * (1 - Group)) / sum(Value * Group), .by = "Var1")
  Var1       Div
1    a 0.5000000
2    b 0.2000000
3    c 0.3333333
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using `pivot_wider()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Group, values_from = Value) %>%   
  mutate(Div = `0` / `1`, .keep = "unused")  

 Var1    Div
  <chr> <dbl>
1 a     0.5  
2 b     0.2  
3 c     0.333
```

Answer (score 3):

A trick that takes use of values from `Group`

```
aggregate(
    cbind(Div = Value^(1 - 2 * Group)) ~ Var1,
    quux,
    prod
)
```

Which gives

```
  Var1       Div
1    a 0.5000000
2    b 0.2000000
3    c 0.3333333
```

Answer (score 2):

The data.table package can do similar manipulations. In this case, the group names of 0 and 1 need to be renamed to nonnumeric column names.

```
library(data.table) 
DT<-data.table(
   Var1=rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 2),   
   Group=as.factor(c(rep("0", 3), rep("1", 3))), 
   Value=c(1:3, 2, 10, 9))
DT2<-dcast(DT,  Var1 ~ Group)
setnames(DT2, c("0", "1"), c("Group0", "Group1"))
DT2[, .(Var1, Group0/Group1)]
```

Actually, DT2[, "0"] and DT2[, "1"] would give correct vectors without this change (and they can be divided yielding a vector of results without the Var1 label), it just won't recognize numbers as group names for operations within the [].

Answer (score 1):

```
%let pgm=utl-calculations-involving-a-sql-self-join-in-wps-r-and-python;

Calculations involving a sql self join in wps r and python

github
https://github.com/rogerjdeangelis/utl-calculations-involving-a-sql-self-join-in-wps-r-and-python

No need for sepaate tables

    Five solutions

        1 wps proc sql
        2 wps proc r sql
        3 wps proc python sql
        4 R solution by
          https://stackoverflow.com/users/3358272/r2evans
        5 wps merge

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76885825/find-the-ratio-between-two-groups

/*                   _
(_)_ __  _ __  _   _| |_
| | `_ \| `_ \| | | | __|
| | | | | |_) | |_| | |_
|_|_| |_| .__/ \__,_|\__|
        |_|
*/

/*---- changes groups to groups due to restritions in some languages     ----*/

options validvarname=upcase;
libname sd1 "d:/sd1";
data sd1.have;

  input Var1 $1. Groups Value;

cards4;
a 0 1
b 0 2
c 0 3
a 1 2
b 1 10
c 1 9
;;;;
run;quit;

/**************************************************************************************************************************/
/*                            |                                                   |                                       */
/*                            |                                                   |                                       */
/* SD1.HAVE total obs=6       | RILES                                             | OUTPUT                                */
/*                            |                                                   |                                       */
/* Obs  VAR1  GROUPS  VALUE   |     var1          DIV                             |     var1          DIV                 */
/*                            |                                                   |                                       */
/*  1    a       0       1    |  1     a    0.5000000  a(1)/a(4)  = 1/2  = .5     |  1     a    0.5000000                 */
/*  2    b       0       2    |  2     b    0.2000000  b(2)/a(5)  = 2/10 = .2     |  2     b    0.2000000                 */
/*  3    c       0       3    |  3     c    0.3333333  c(3)/a(6)  = 3/9  = .3333  |  3     c    0.3333333                 */
/*  4    a       1       2    |                                                   |                                       */
/*  5    b       1      10    |                                                   |                                       */
/*  6    c       1       9    |                                                   |                                       */
/*                            |                                                   |                                       */
/**************************************************************************************************************************/

/*                                                         _
/ | __      ___ __  ___   _ __  _ __ ___   ___   ___  __ _| |
| | \ \ /\ / / `_ \/ __| | `_ \| `__/ _ \ / __| / __|/ _` | |
| |  \ V  V /| |_) \__ \ | |_) | | | (_) | (__  \__ \ (_| | |
|_|   \_/\_/ | .__/|___/ | .__/|_|  \___/ \___| |___/\__, |_|
             |_|         |_|                            |_|
*/

proc datasets lib=sd1 nolist nodetails;delete want; run;quit;

%utl_submit_wps64x('
libname sd1 "d:/sd1";
options validvarname=any;
proc sql;
  create
     table sd1.want as
  select
    l.var1
   ,l.value/r.value as DIV
  from
    sd1.have as l, sd1.have as r
  where
        l.groups = 0 and r.groups = 1
    and l.var1   = r.var1
;quit;
proc print data=sd1.want;
run;quit;
');

/**************************************************************************************************************************/
/*                                                                                                                        */
/* The WPS System                                                                                                         */
/*                                                                                                                        */
/*  Obs    VAR1        div                                                                                                */
/*                                                                                                                        */
/*   1      a               0.5                                                                                           */
/*   2      b               0.2                                                                                           */
/*   3      c      0.3333333333                                                                                           */
/*                                                                                                                        */
/**************************************************************************************************************************/

/*___                                                                 _
|___ \  __      ___ __  ___   _ __  _ __ ___   ___   _ __   ___  __ _| |
  __) | \ \ /\ / / `_ \/ __| | `_ \| `__/ _ \ / __| | `__| / __|/ _` | |
 / __/   \ V  V /| |_) \__ \ | |_) | | | (_) | (__  | |    \__ \ (_| | |
|_____|   \_/\_/ | .__/|___/ | .__/|_|  \___/ \___| |_|    |___/\__, |_|
                 |_|         |_|                                   |_|
*/
%utl_submit_wps64x('

libname sd1 "d:/sd1";
proc datasets lib=sd1 nolist nodetails;delete want; run;quit;

proc r;
export data=sd1.have r=have;
submit;
library(sqldf);
have;
want <- sqldf("
  select
    l.var1
   ,l.value/r.value as div
  from
    have as l inner join have as r
  on
        l.groups  = 0 and r.groups = 1
    and l.var1   = r.var1
";);
want;
endsubmit;
import r=want data=sd1.want;
run;quit;
');

/*____                                                          _   _                             _
|___ /  __      ___ __  ___   _ __  _ __ ___   ___  _ __  _   _| |_| |__   ___  _ __    ___  __ _| |
  |_ \  \ \ /\ / / `_ \/ __| | `_ \| `__/ _ \ / __|| `_ \| | | | __| `_ \ / _ \| `_ \  / __|/ _` | |
 ___) |  \ V  V /| |_) \__ \ | |_) | | | (_) | (__ | |_) | |_| | |_| | | | (_) | | | | \__ \ (_| | |
|____/    \_/\_/ | .__/|___/ | .__/|_|  \___/ \___|| .__/ \__, |\__|_| |_|\___/|_| |_| |___/\__, |_|
                 |_|         |_|                   |_|    |___/                                |_|

*/

%utl_submit_wps64x('

libname sd1 "d:/sd1";
proc datasets lib=sd1 nolist nodetails;delete want; run;quit;

proc python;
export data=sd1.have python=have;
submit;
 from os import path;
 import pandas as pd;
 import numpy as np;
 import pandas as pd;
 from pandasql import sqldf;
 mysql = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals());
 from pandasql import PandaSQL;
 pdsql = PandaSQL(persist=True);
 sqlite3conn = next(pdsql.conn.gen).connection.connection;
 sqlite3conn.enable_load_extension(True);
 sqlite3conn.load_extension("c:/temp/libsqlitefunctions.dll");
 mysql = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals());
 want=pdsql("""
  select
    l.var1
   ,l.value/r.value as div
  from
    have as l inner join have as r
  on
        l.groups = 0 and r.groups = 1
    and l.var1   = r.var1

 """);
print(want);
endsubmit;
import data=sd1.want python=want;
run;quit;
proc print data=sd1.want;
run;quit;
');

/*  _
| || |    _ __
| || |_  | `__|
|__   _| | |
   |_|   |_|

*/

%utl_submit_wps64x('
libname sd1 "d:/sd1";
proc r;
export data=sd1.have r=have;
submit;
library(dplyr);
have %>%
  group_by(VAR1) %>%
  filter(all(0:1 %in% GROUPS)) %>%
  summarize(DIV = VALUE[GROUPS==0]/VALUE[GROUPS==1]);
have;
endsubmit;
import r=want data=sd1.want;
run;quit;
');

/**************************************************************************************************************************/
/*                                                                                                                        */
/* The WPS System                                                                                                         */
/*                                                                                                                        */
/*                                                                                                                        */
/* R                                                                                                                      */
/*                                                                                                                        */
/* # A tibble: 3 x 2                                                                                                      */
/*                                                                                                                        */
/*   VAR1    DIV                                                                                                          */
/*   <chr> <dbl>                                                                                                          */
/*                                                                                                                        */
/* 1 a     0.5                                                                                                            */
/* 2 b     0.2                                                                                                            */
/* 3 c     0.333                                                                                                          */
/*                                                                                                                        */
/* WPS                                                                                                                    */
/*                                                                                                                        */
/*   VAR1 GROUPS VALUE                                                                                                    */
/* 1    a      0     1                                                                                                    */
/* 2    b      0     2                                                                                                    */
/* 3    c      0     3                                                                                                    */
/* 4    a      1     2                                                                                                    */
/* 5    b      1    10                                                                                                    */
/* 6    c      1     9                                                                                                    */
/*                                                                                                                        */
/**************************************************************************************************************************/

/*___
| ___|  __      ___ __  ___   _ __ ___   ___ _ __ __ _  ___
|___ \  \ \ /\ / / `_ \/ __| | `_ ` _ \ / _ \ `__/ _` |/ _ \
 ___) |  \ V  V /| |_) \__ \ | | | | | |  __/ | | (_| |  __/
|____/    \_/\_/ | .__/|___/ |_| |_| |_|\___|_|  \__, |\___|
                 |_|                             |___/
*/

%utl_submit_wps64x('

libname sd1 "d:/sd1";

data sd1.want;

  merge sd1.have(where=(groups=0) rename=value=top)
        sd1.have(where=(groups=1) rename=value=bot)
  ;

  div = top/bot;

  drop groups;

run;quit;
');

/**************************************************************************************************************************/
/*                                                                                                                        */
/* SD1.WANT total obs=3                                                                                                   */
/*                                                                                                                        */
/* Obs    VAR1    TOP    BOT      DIV                                                                                     */
/*                                                                                                                        */
/*  1      a       1       2    0.50000                                                                                   */
/*  2      b       2      10    0.20000                                                                                   */
/*  3      c       3       9    0.33333                                                                                   */
/*                                                                                                                        */
/**************************************************************************************************************************/


/*              _
  ___ _ __   __| |
 / _ \ `_ \ / _` |
|  __/ | | | (_| |
 \___|_| |_|\__,_|

*/
```